# How do I get an admin view of Code Workbook modules?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

How do I obtain a view of all of the modules, the users, mode, job type, as well of the specifics about the spark module (number of executors, memory etc) in Code Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You can access this view using the admin account: `https://<FOUNDRY_URL>/workspace/vector/admin`

This will provide you with a detailed view of the modules, number of executors, driver cores & memory, executor cores & memory.